# How do you use .htaccess mod_rewrite to change the following

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

How do I use Mod_Rewrite to change the following URL?

`main/order/$var to /$var`.

I am already using .htaccess to rewrite `/.index.php/$var` to `/$var`. this is a codeigniter setup.  Therefore the full URL would be `/.index.php/main/order/$var`.

Here is my current file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|stats)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/main/order/$1 [L]
```

I am receiving a misconfuguration error when attempting to tweak this.

Comment: Well, why don't you simply extend the existing pattern, since you say it works and you only want to modify it. You already know how.

Comment: If you really have a specific issue here, then name it. And please post your existing code.

Comment: Added the current file. Sorry for not including upfront. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but that certainly is _not_ a working version of a `.htaccess` style file. `RewriteCond $1` does not make any sense at all. What is `$1` meant to express here?

Answer (score 0):

I am confused, you claim you posted a working version of the `.htaccess` style file, but that looks more like an attempt you made. The `index.php` in the `RewriteRule` looks funny to me (but I don't know codeigniter well), and it certainly should *not* appear in both, that`RewriteCond` *and* a `RewriteRule`...

Your `RewriteRule` in there looks fine, but I suggest to use that `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|stats)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/main/order/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I'm receiving a 500 internal server error when using the above.  

Error from apache log: AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Comment: Sorry, I indeed forgot the `index.php` inside the condition is required to prevent such a redirection loop. Should work now :-)

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a unique codeigniter scenario.  I got this working using the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots\.txt|css|js|stats)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I then had to configure routes.php as follows

```
$route['main'] = 'main/order';
$route['(:any)'] = 'main/order/$1';
```

Comment: I still cannot make any sense of that `RewriteCond` but anyway, if it does what you want, great!